# activating python venv on windows

Tags: virtualenv

```
venv\Scripts\activate : The module 'venv' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module venv'.
At line:1 char:1
+ venv\Scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (venv\Scripts\activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
```

how to activate the virtual venv on windows

Comment: Are you at the right location when running the command? You must be in the parent directory of the venv (i e, the folder where venv is present)